# Databricks Spark Cassandra connectivity throwing exception: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, spark-cassandra-connector

I have installed the Cassandra DB in Azure Virtual Machine and want to perform read/write operation through the Azure Databricks. I am going through the Databricks offcial [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/cassandra.html) which does not help me in configuration.
I am sharing below my code cum configurations details:

```
%sh
ping -c 2 vmname.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
```

**Response received:**

```
PING vmname.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com (13.69.10.10): 56 data bytes
--- vmname.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

```
// define the cluster name and cassandra host name
val sparkClusterName = "adbazewdobucluster"
val cassandraHostIP = "vmname.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com"

dbutils.fs.put(s"/databricks/init/$sparkClusterName/cassandra.sh",
  s"""
     #!/usr/bin/bash
     echo '[driver]."spark.cassandra.connection.host" = "$cassandraHostIP"' >> /home/ubuntu/databricks/common/conf/cassandra.conf
   """.trim, true)

// setting IP of the Cassandra server
spark.conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")

//verify sparkconf is set properly
spark.conf.get("spark.cassandra.connection.host")
```

and after applying all the configuration in spark I am trying to retrieve the records from the table resides in Cassandra DB, which is throwing the exception.

```
val df = sqlContext
  .read
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map( "table" -> "words_new", "keyspace" -> "test"))
  .load
df.explain
```

**Exception:**

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect))
```

I have checked the my Cassandra DB is running and read/write operation working fine directly.
So my **question is**: Am I applying the configuration in a right way? If not so then How do I access the Cassandra from the Databricks notebook.
I am using Scala for the Spark framework and my cluster and driver versions are as following:

```
Databricks Runtime Version
6.2 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.4, Scala 2.11)

spark-cassandra-connector
com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.4.1

cassandra version: 3.11.4
```

Comment: Ping isn't working either... `100% packet loss`

Comment: *Apache Spark 2.4.4* should use `:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.4.4`, by the way

Comment: @cricket_007 Let me retry.. can you please tell me the exact steps to connect.

Comment: @cricket_007 the same output has shown in the databricks notebook :2 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss

Comment: @cricket_007 the highest version I can see is: `2.4.1` for the Scala version `2.11`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running on Azure.. make sure to set broadcast_rpc_address to public IP address or dns hostname these settings must work for you -

Set rpc address to ip address of your network interface attached to your VM..on Windows - Hyper V Interface.

```
rpc_address: <**private ip** of your vm >
```

broadcast rpc address to public ip, on this ip external clients should get response from cassandra on port 9042

```
broadcast_rpc_address: <**public ip** or hostname.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com>
```

listen address as default to localhost / 127.0.0.1

```
listen_address: **localhost**
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the outputs you posted, you are getting `NoHostAvailableException` because you are connecting to `localhost` which isn't accessible. That's because you've set the C* host as `localhost` here:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
```

You need to set it to this value:

```
val cassandraHostIP = "vmname.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com"
```

Cheers!

Comment: I update connection.host `127.0.0.1` to `vmname.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com` but getting the same exception.

Comment: @Stark Do you need to enable the Azure VPC to accept traffic from Databricks?